# Is the solution given by Laplace transform a weak solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms

This is a problem [appeared at Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145416/1871). The OP wants to solve the following initial-boundary value problem of transport equation:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$$
$$u(x,0)=x^2,u(0,t)=t$$

It can be easiliy shown the problem doesn't have a classical solution satisfying the i.c. and b.c. simultaneously, but one can still find a "solution" with the help of Laplace transform:

```
(* Corresponding _Mathematica_ code *)
{eq, ic, bc} = {D[u[x, t], x] == D[u[x, t], t], u[x, 0] == x^2, 
     u[0, t] == t};
teqn = LaplaceTransform[{eq, bc}, t, s] /. HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a /. 
  Rule @@ ic
tsol = u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[teqn, u[x, t], x] 
sol[x_, t_] = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t]
```

$$u(x,t)=\left(-t^2-2 t x+t-x^2+x\right) \theta (t+x)+(t+x)^2$$

where $\theta$ is Heaviside step function. Further check shows this solution satisfies the equation except for $t+x=0$, the b.c. except for $t<0$ and the i.c. except for $x>0$.

So my question is, what have I found with Laplace transform? Is this the so-called weak solution? Well, to be honest, due to my poor math basis, I can't understand the description on the [wikipedia page of weak solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution#General_case) very well, but $e^{-st}$ seems not to be a function with "compact support"?